# maven built android library, problem with Unity import

Tags: java, android, maven, unity-game-engine

I am building an Android library using maven. 
Works fine, I can import the jars into an normal Android Studio Project, everything working fine.

However, when I try to build a Unity project using the exact same jars, I get following error: File 'META-INF/LICENSE' exists in both

So maven is creating those files in both jars.

I did not found anything on how to tell maven to only copy it into one jar, or in none.

Anyone an idea how to fix that problem?

Cheers

Comment: OK, I already got a kind of "hack", since the jar file are zipped, you can delete those files using winrar or something like that.
But would be nice if anybody has a better solution!

Comment: Without the full pom file and more informations it's impossible to help..furthermore are you using android-maven-plugin ? Which version of Maven are you using ? Which Java versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use with Custom Gradle.

[Android build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Fgy.png)
Custom Gradle file

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {**ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "maven url"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {**ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url "maven url"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compileOnly files ('libs/unity-classes.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    
**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**]
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```